# Twitter Bootstrap Fluid row horizontal alignment

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've a fluid row in which i have a item (nontext) and I want to align it horizontal centered

text

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12" style="text-align: center">
            <img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/Domain/IMG_1710.jpg")" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this works pretty fine

but as soon as I add a **max-width** and **max-height** the alignment doesn't work anymore.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12"  style="text-align: center;max-height: 300px; max-width: 400px" >
            <img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/Domain/IMG_1710.jpg")" />

    </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong ? How can I set max width and hight and have a centered alignment?

Comment: put the css on the image itself?

Comment: why not use the .offset class to position the span

Comment: how do i have to apply the offset class ? do you have an example ?

Comment: Setting the style on the image itself doesnt help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To follow bootstrap rules, try to center it with the `offset` class

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4 offset4">
        <img src="yourimage" />
    </div>
</div>
```

[see documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem)

Answer (score 0):

Applying `max-height` and `max-width` on one of Bootstrap's `span#` classes will override grid styling. I would recommend adding the height/width on the image (if the text align doesn't work, you can try `margin: 0 auto` on the image.